Why is IndexDB not working in the extension?
I'm writing a browser extension. In the service worker console, I practiced working with indexdb. I use a standard template to create a store, but nothing happens. The IndexDB Application section remains empty.
let db
let request = indexedDB.open("test_db");

request.onupgradeneeded = function (event) {
    db = event.target.result;
    db.createObjectStore('books', {keyPath: 'id'});
}

request.onerror = function (event) {
  console.error("Why didn't you allow my web app to use IndexedDB?!");
}

request.onsuccess = function (event) {
  db = event.target.result;
}

As you can understand, the Manifest version is 3.
Browser information:
Chromium: 112.0.5615.49 Built on Ubuntu , running on Ubuntu 18.04 (32 bit)
JavaScript: V8 11.2.214.9

I checked the operation of the code on the browser pages and the code works.
Permissions for using storage are written in the manifest.


Devtools for service worker doesn't show storage. Open any other page of your extension and you'll see storage in its devtools. If you don't have any pages, open devtools for the background script-> Sources tab -> files tree on the left -> right-click your script, click "open in new tab". 2) There's no need for storage permissions in manifest.json to use web storage APIs.


@wOxxOm 1) That is, IndexDB works in service workers, but the data recorded in DB will be not visible in DevTools? At the same time, I see a BD of background scripts. Or are they visible on background pages, but not visible in service worker? But I also can't catch the execution of events in the debugger. Not onupgradeneeded, not onsuccess, not onerror. But the db variable gets the IDBDatabase object. If I call db.createObjectStore('books', {keyPath: 'id'}), an error is returned The database is not running a version change transaction. It trns out that the DB is not being creat

Devtools for service workers can't show storage. The code itself can be debugged, but if the db already exists, onupgradeneeded won't be called because you didn't increase the version parameter in open(). Open a page as I described and you'll be able to debug the service worker, start/stop it, and view storage.

@wOxxOm Aaaaa. Okay, now im understand. Thank you!
